# Unable to get the whole list of products when mapping through it, getting only the last added item in the list in the component

Tags: reactjs, blockchain, smartcontracts, web3js, metamask

I'm a developing a marketplace `DApp` where sellers can list products for sale and buyers can purchase it using ethers. i'm using `Metamask` as a wallet and `ganche` as my loaclly running blockchain.

As the seller adds the product for sale it shows up in the buy component for buyers to purchase, but as one more product is added for sale, the buy component only shows the latest added product for sale and not all the products.

I'm using `map` function to map through the array of products, below is the code which returns the buyer side component:

```
<tbody id="productList">
   { productList.map((product, key) => {
      return(
        <tr key={key}>
        <th scope="row">{ product.id.toString()}</th>
        <td>{product.name}</td>
        <td>{window.web3.utils.fromWei(product.price.toString(), 'Ether')} ETH</td>
        <td>{product.owner}</td>
        <td>
          { !product.purchased
            ? <button className="btn btn-primary"
                  name={product.id}
                  value={product.price}
                  onClick{purchaseProduct(e.target.name, e.target.value)                                                            }}                                                       >Buy
              </button>
            : <button className="btn btn-success">Owned</button>
          }
         </td>
         </tr>
       );
     })}
</tbody>
```

`productList` is the state containing the product list being passed down from the `App.js` and the `loadBlockchainData` function where we connect to the smart contract and define productList:

```
const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);  
const [account, setAccount] = useState("");
const [marketplace, setMarketplace] = useState("");
const [productList, setProducts] = useState([]);


const loadBlockchainData = async () => {
    const web3 = window.web3;

    const accounts = await web3.eth.getAccounts();

    setAccount(accounts[0]);
    const networkId = await web3.eth.net.getId();
    const networkData = Marketplace.networks[networkId]
    if (networkData) {
      const marketplace = new web3.eth.Contract(Marketplace.abi, networkData.address);
      // console.log(marketplace);
      setMarketplace(marketplace);
      const productCount = await marketplace.methods.productCount().call();
      // console.log(productCount.toString());
      setProductCount(productCount);
      for (var i = 1; i <= productCount; i++) {
        const product = await marketplace.methods.products(i).call();
        setProducts([...productList, product]);
        console.log(productList);

      }
      setLoading(false);
    } else {
      window.alert("Marketplace contract not deployed to detected network.");
      // setloading2(true);
    }
  };
```

Also, after clicking on the buy button the page needs to be refreshed manually to change the `Buy` button to `Owned`, the state does not update automatically, how can that be implemented.

Comment: you need to share your parent and child component code for this case. Also i would suggest not to use setProducts inside loop. Instead make a variable list and simply do all operations on list variable inside loop and then finally use setProducts(list) outside loop.